# Associate each article with relevant information

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Wikipedia API in my project and want to associate every item (article in wikipedia) with relevant information about an article (also from wikipedia). For example Confucius shuold be related to Confucius' bio, Confucius University to relevant info about University and so on and so for. When i loop through it brings about a mess. For example
[image]

It is seen from the picture that headings (Confucius) is not relevant to text below in red. I know that the issue with for loop and i tried different methods but fail. Please help me out!

```
  var wikirequest = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(wikiData) {

        // Fetch the biographical information
        var bioName = wikiData[2][0];

        // Check if instead of bio there is a phrase "The article may refer to...." if so then change indices
        if (bioName.indexOf('may refer to') >= 0) {
          bioName = wikiData[2][1];
        } else {
          var bioName = wikiData[2][0];
        }

        var wikiArcticles = wikiData[1];  
        var wikiArticlesShortInfo = wikiData[2]

        console.log("This is short info "+ wikiArticlesShortInfo);

        //domCache.$wikiArticlesList.empty();
        domCache.$wikiArticlesList.html('');

        for (var i=0; i < wikiArcticles.length; i++) {
          for ( var j=0; j <wikiArticlesShortInfo.length; j++ ) {
            console.log("Each short story " + wikiArticlesShortInfo[j]);
            console.log("Each article " + wikiArcticles[i]);
            domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '<br>'+  '<span class="shortInfo">'+                                         wikiArticlesShortInfo[j]+'</span>'+ '</li>'); 
          }
        }

        // Short biography
        console.log(bioName);
        console.log(wikiArcticles);
        console.log(url);

        domCache.$bioDiv.text(bioName); 

      } // end of success
    });
  }// wikirequest

  wikirequest();
```

[My project in CodePen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var j=0; j < wikiData.length; j++) {
        var articleAuthor = wikiData[1][j];
        var articleInfo = wikiData[2][j];
        var linkAuthor = wikiData[3][j];

        domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ '<span>' + '<a href =' + linkAuthor + ' target="_blank" >' + articleAuthor + '</a>' + '</span>' +'<span class="shortInfo">' + articleInfo +'</span>' + '</li>');

        // Check if some articles are undefined if so hide them
        if (articleAuthor === "undefined") {
          $('.articleItem').html('');
        }

        //console.log(j + " " + articleAuthor);
        //console.log(j + " " + articleInfo);
        //console.log(j + " " + linkAuthor);
  }
```